# Boton con jquery no hace nada

Tags: javascript, jquery, botón

Estoy tratando de hacer algo y he empezado con la parte más sencilla, mostrar un mensaje cuando se da click en un botón con jquery, busqué en internet y lo intenté de varios modos, pero el botón simplemente no hace nada.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <TITLE></TITLE>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">         
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <br>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="plantillas.php">Plantillas</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="index.html">Inicio </a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="facturacion.php">Facturación</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="iniciar_sesion.php">Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="registrarse.php">Registrarse</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="buscador_de_plantillas.php">Buscador de plantillas</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <br><br>            

    <h1 align='center'>Facturación</h1> 
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" name="btnPaciente"  id="btnPaciente" value="Agregar 5"/>

    <br><br>
    <select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3">option3</option>
        <option value="option4">option4</option>    
    </select>

    <br><br>
    <div id="footer" >
        <div id="f1" style="float:left; width: 600px; padding: 0px 60px;">
        Sublime es una plataforma líder en desarrollo web, basada en el sistema "en la nube", que tiene millones de usuarios alrededor del mundo. Ahora es más fácil tener una presencia online profesional.<br><br>
        Promociona tu negocio, exhibe tu arte, configura una tienda online o solo explora nuevas ideas. El creador de páginas web tiene todo lo que necesitas para crear un sitio web totalmente personalizado, gratuito y de alta calidad.
        </div>
        <div id="f2" style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">
            <a href="plantillas.php">Plantillas</a><br><br>
            <a href="facturacion.php">Facturación</a><br><br>
            <a href="iniciar_sesion.php">Iniciar Sesión</a><br><br>
            <a href="registrarse.php">Registrarse</a><br><br>
            <a href="buscador_de_plantillas.php">Buscador de plantillas</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','#btnPaciente',function(){
        alert("1");
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){   

        $("#btnPaciente").click(crear);

        function crear(){
            alert("1");
        }

        $("input[btnPaciente]").click(function(){
            alert("2");
        }

        $("#btnPaciente").on("click", function() 
        {
            alert("DD");            

        });
    }); 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu principal problema es que estas incluyendo jQuery después de intentar usarlo.. subilo arriba del script que escribiste!

Comment: @JhonHernández puedes revisar la consola en el **chrome*** para ver que error te está saliendo.

Comment: Era cierto...hay que poner primero <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @JhonHernández el de jQuery antes que el de Bootstrap, ya que Bootstrap usa jQuery, asi que tiene que estar definido a la hora de cargarlo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema, se da debido al orden en el que estas haciendo las cosas.

Por un lado, en tu script, estas utilizando jQuery, pero aún no lo has definido, ya que la carga, la has echo luego.

Por otro lado, tenes el mismo error con la inclusión de Bootstrap, como podes ver en su [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/), tiene como dependencia a jQuery (por lo que la librería de Bootstrap necesita que jQuery ya se encuentre definido previamente para funcionar de manera correcta)

En fin, tendrías que ordenarlos de la siguiente manera

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','#btnPaciente',function(){
    alert("1");
});

$(document).ready(function(){   

    $("#btnPaciente").click(crear);

    function crear(){
        alert("1");
    }

    $("input[btnPaciente]").click(function(){
        alert("2");
    }

    $("#btnPaciente").on("click", function() 
    {
        alert("DD");            

    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

A parte del orden de los script, como dicen los compañeros, tienes un error en el código. de la función que tiene el alert("2"):

```
 $("input[btnPaciente]").click(function(){
        alert("2");
} //aquí hay que cerrar el paréntesis de la fx click
```

Además, el selector no es correcto. La función quedaría así:

```
$("input[name='btnPaciente']").click(function(){
        alert("2");
    })
```

De esta forma, funcionan todos.